# Umbraco Forms Datasource Webservice

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco-forms

I'm using Umbraco Forms in a new websites. This website has Merchello enabled, so I got products in there too. I want to create an enquiry/request form and collect the **country of requester** (so I shall show a full list of countries), and enable requester to **select products** they are interested in too.

Thus, the form will have fields like Countries drop down list as well as products to choose from. For countries I have got them all listed in a config file, and created a web api that **inherits from UmbracoApiController** - when creating the form in the back office I get the method invoked successfully but receive an error when returning the list. Whereas to access products list I shall **inherit from MerchelloApiController**, which when I do I could never invoke the api controller.

Two questions:
1. How could I show the list of countries (reading from file or service)?
2. How could I access Merchello products list to populate Products' drop down list on Umbraco forms?

Comment: and the question is....?

Comment: Please include details of the errors that you're getting. Examples of code would also be useful.

Comment: @MarioLopez I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yo should use Prevalue Sources instead a Webservice Datasource. [Datasources](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/umbraco-pro/contour/documentation/Editor/Creating-Forms-Based-on-Datasources/) are to map Umbraco Form fields to external services.

With [Prevalue Sources](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/umbraco-pro/contour/documentation/Editor/Defining-and-Attaching-Prevaluesources/) you can get data to populate your dropdowns. You say you have your countries in a fie already so you could use the 'Get values from textfile' type.

To get your Merchello products you could probably use [NuPickers](https://github.com/uComponents/nuPickers). You could create a data type of [DotNet type](https://github.com/uComponents/nuPickers/wiki/Data-Source-DotNet) and select your source class that will return a list of your products. Then create a Prevalues source of type 'Umbraco datatype prevalues' that uses this datatype to get the data to populate your dropdown.

I hope all this info will put you in the right track.